# The tangent to $1/x$ forms a triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem:** The tangent to $f(x)=1/x$ forms a triangle with the x-axis and the y-axis. Find the area of this triangle.

**Attempt:** I pick some x value $x_0$ which gives me a y value $1/x_0$. So I have one point. I know that the slope of my line at this point is $k=f'(x_0)=-x_0^{-2}$. So I have a point and I have a slope, so I know what the line is.

I don't know how to proceed. Two approaches:

1. See where the line hits x and y axis.
2. Find the equation of the line and integrate from $x=0$ to $x=-m/k$.

Comment: Hint: If you can use your slope and point to find the x and y intercepts then you can use the formula $A=\frac{1}{2}bh$.

Comment: Both approaches will work, but the first one is better by far. You get a right triangle with known baseline length and height, so you have the area immediately. Oh, and I can't resist the urge to chide you a little bit: When you see two possible approaches, which is two more than some will see, why on earth don't you *try* them and see what happens? It's not the end of the world if you try something and then it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 2):

What I like to do in a situation like this is to just memorize one formula
$$m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$
Terms like *point-slope* and *slope-intercept* are just forms of ambient noise to me
e.g.
$$
m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\color{blue}{\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}}=\frac{y-b}{x-0}=\frac{y-0}{x-\text{x-intercept}}=\text{etc.}
$$

Continuing, we have
$$m=\frac{1}{-x_0^2}=\frac{y-\frac{1}{x_0}}{x-x_o}$$
which gives
$$y=0\implies x=2x_0$$
$$x=0\implies y=\frac{2}{x_0}$$

and the area is given by
$$\frac{1}{2}BH=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(2x_0\bigg)\bigg(\frac{2}{x_0}\bigg)=2$$
or
$$\int_0^{2x_0}f(t)dt, \text{where }\frac{f(t)-0}{x-2x_0}=\frac{1}{-x^2_0}$$
$$\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

the equation of the tangente in $x_0$ is given by $$y=\frac{-1}{x_0^2}(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$$
Moreover,
$$y=0\iff x=x_0^2f(x_0)+x_0.$$
Therefore, the area is given by 
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot B\cdot h=\frac{1}{2}f(x_0)\left(x_0^2f(x_0)+x_0\right).$$

Comment: But $h$ should be the intersection with the y-axis, not $f(x_0)$ I know that the answer is: it is constant.

Comment: Ok, got it now. Base = 2/a and Height = 2a So Area=2.